# Mixing multiple testing frameworks & suites together

Tags: testing, tdd, bdd

Does anyone know a good way to mix and merge multiple testing frameworks together so that they can all be run in batch and return an solid overall total of which tests failed for which frameworks and suites/specs.

So lets say my testing setup for a particular project looks like so:

- I'm using `Rails` (Ruby) and using `RSpec` to test that.
- I'm also using `Cucumber` with my `Rails` application.
- I'm using `MochaJS` with the `Testacular runner` for `JavaScript` testing.
- I'm using `Jasmine` to test for some `NodeJS` applications that I'm using as well.

Now to test each of these test groups I would have to launch each of their respective frameworks/instances, start and run the "run tests" operation for each, and then tally up the results and figure out which tests failed and which ones didn't.

Does anyone know of a tool that is designed to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a build automation software to perform all these task together. 
Whenever one of your test process fails you'll get a detailed feedback.

As you're developing a ruby application maybe Buildr is the best choice, but you could as well use Ant or Rant...
you can find a complete list of tools is here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software